# How to set placeholder with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, placeholder

Please take a look at this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/KA85s/3/

JQ-UI sets first option as default. I don't want it to be happened: instead I want to set HTML5 placeholder.

How can I set HTML 5 placeholder (instead of first available `<option>`) for these JS generated inputs?

[image]

Comment: Please include the relevant code within your question.

Comment: @JamesMontagne I placed JSfiddle link. Code is huge. No one will read this question without live example

Comment: I wasn't saying you should remove the jsfiddle, but it is generally useful to include the **relevant** code to the question within the question.  If jsfiddle ceases to exist, the question should still be useful to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mohamed Meligy came with the same solution

http://jsfiddle.net/KA85s/8/

Though i used something else..

here is how it works when your input element is created with use jQuery to give it a placholder attribute and we are done :D

** UPDATED **

http://jsfiddle.net/KA85s/19/

added custom default value :D

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
input.attr("placeholder", value);
```

Updated jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Meligy/KA85s/5/

In the example I just replaced your `val()` call, obviously, you can completely remove the part from the function and add it separately with any text you want.

Comment: You changed whole function. but how to set different placeholder for #qsubject and #qsubject2 ?

Answer (score 2):

This will do all you need without cross browser compatibility issue i have tested in ie7,8,9 runs perfect.

```
<input type="text" value="Search" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search';}">
```

good luck!

Comment: Just a small improvement changing colors as well:

onfocus="if (this.value == 'Type your email') {this.value = ''; this.style.color='#333'}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Type your email'; this.style.color='#BBB'}"

Comment: @Aamir Shahzad: thanks! You solved my problem with this cross browser trick! Thanks!